# Renewcommand within an environment doesn't persist

Tags: macros, environments

I'd like to be able to change the behavior of my environment commands by another command. They should be changed until the end of the environment. This is what I thought would happen if I made a `newcommand` inside an environment, and `renew`'d it with another command. But turns out, it somehow reverts back to the old definition the next time it is called.

The purpose of this trickery is to specify a new kind of tabular layout. How could I make the new definition persist?

---

Here's an example.

[image: Example image]

These rows should both look like the topmost line. Here's the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{score}{%
    % Define commands
    \newcommand{\chords}[1]{
        \end{tabular}\par
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{8}{@{}l}}
        & ##1 \\[-0.2em]
    }
    \newcommand{\nolyrics}{
        \renewcommand{\chords}[1]{
            \end{tabular}\par
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}ll*{3}{|*{2}{l}}}
            & ####1 \\[-0.2em]
        }
    }
    % Layout
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
}{
    \end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{score}
    \nolyrics % Specifies a new layout for the score
    \chords{Fm && D && A && B & C} % This is fine
    \chords{D && E && D/F && C} % This is not similarly laid out
\end{score}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Each cell in a tabular is a group, so any normal `\renewcommand` changes stays in that group, so as soon as you run the next `\coords` the change is gone.

Comment: @daleif Of course! Thanks for pointing that out. I'd love to accept an answer if it's worth writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each cell in a tabular forms a group. So this is essentially equivalent to

```
\begingroup
  \nolyrics rededefines \chords
  execute new \chords
  \chords ends the current cell (inserts a & + \\) and thus the group
\endgroup
\begingroup
execute original \chords
...
```

Instead of `\renewcommand` you could use `\gdef\chords####1{`